# Is there a danger in having a high number (20+) of simple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am writing a game in Java. I have in-game tutorials. Each tutorial is essentially a 5-10 frame animation that changes every second.

For each tutorial, I have a simple thread running:

```
int sleepTimeMillis = 1000;
public static void run() {
    while ( true ) {
        try {
            tutorialFrame = ( tutorialFrame + 1 ) % numberOfFrames;
            Thread.sleep ( sleepTimeMillis );
        catch ( InterruptedException e ) {}
    }
}
```

I currently have about 10 of these running. By the time I finish all of them, I imagine I'll have about 50.

Otherwise, my game uses a handful of threads: One for the windowing environment, one for the game logic, one for the rendering engine, and probably a handful of other small ones here and there.

Unsurprisingly, I haven't noticed any speed issues in the game by adding these threads. That being said, I'm not knowledgeable on the behind-the-scenes overhead for having many threads within a process.

I could restructure the program in a different way if it is desirable to reduce the number of these tutorial threads.

So I'm asking whether it's worth the time to re-structure the tutorials a little so they all share one thread, or whether it makes sense to just leave things how they are.

Thanks!

Comment: You should consider systems where the number of cores are less.. There, the speed might decrease *considerably*

Comment: Even for threads that only increments a variable once every second, or half-a-second?

Comment: use thread pool via executor service instead. please always keep in mind, that thread creation is expensive and frequent context switching (which would happen in case of many threads) is not good thing too.

Comment: @JoshuaD btw, for the recurrent tasks you can use Timer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: Because of this: `Thread.sleep ( sleepTimeMillis );` your threads are idle most time. So I believe it's okay. You can create 500 and you won't even notice performance degradation.

Comment: "high" and "low", "big" and "small", "many" and "few"---they're all relative terms.  20 threads is "high" if you are used to working with two or three.  It is "low" compared to some application that I work with.

Comment: No. NO. NO, goddammit! This is NOT how (or why) you do multithreading. This is like driving your kids to school on a tank because it will surely get there. You should use a `Timer` or a `ScheduledExecutorService` to do timed or scheduled events without creating such heavy objects as `Thread`s. They will also help alleviate the synchronization and signalling issues that you introduce (you made `tutorialFrame` a `volatile` variable, right?). As to answer your question - no, there's no danger on any modern device that can reasonably run a game (even single core) with a thread count below hundreds

Comment: _I could restructure the program in a different way if it is desirable to reduce the number of these tutorial threads._  It always is desirable to reduce the number of _anything_ if they (whatever they are) aren't needed.  Your "tutorial" threads do almost nothing but sleep.  Why not use timer tasks for that instead?

Comment: @SashaSalauyou  500 threads that do nothing but sleep won't use much CPU, but CPU is not the only resource that is used by threads.  There is also virtual address space, and real memory, and (in some operating systems) limited available process slots.  In many applications, and on many operating systems, even 500 idle threads might not be noticed; but even so, why use those resources when there is a simpler solution (timer tasks) that doesn't use them?

Comment: You should start thinking about Thread and code you want to run in thread as different entities. Runnable/Callable just define what should be done when a run method called. Who is going to call this run, Runnable/Callable don't care. By separating app logic from thread management you would gain loose coupling and better control. After that you can use ExecutorService to submit your task and implement how those task should be run, As I think in your case you would not want them to run concurrently, as user can only follow one tutorial at a time.

Comment: @Ordous: Was there a reason to be unpleasant?

Comment: @nikis: It looks like your solution is the best one. I wasn't aware of that tool. If you would make it an answer rather than a comment, I'd be glad to accept it.

Comment: @JoshuaD Would you have read all of these comments if you got one 5 minutes after posting the question saying "No, there won't be any problems, but it's not a nice thing to do"? If you're not comfortable with reasoning about what *load* will those threads put on your system, then you will not be comfortable solving the *problems* and *bugs* that arise from their use. I do not know of any reasonable way to convey that feeling of unease while maintaining a pleasant and non-patronizing tone that would be accepted by everyone.

Comment: @Ordous: Yes, I definitely will be reading every comment in this thread, even if the consensus turns out to be "in this case it's ok".  What problems concern you? What bugs do you see arising? That's why I posted the thread. My intuition is that there may be something bad in this approach, but it creates simple, clear code to solve a simple problem. I'm hesitant to go down the path of premature and unnecessary optimization.

Comment: @JoshuaD To properly answer *that* question (which is different than the one originally posted), we'd have to know how much do *you* know about Java multithreading. Have you heard about it in theory, and found the neat constructor `new Thread(runnable)` and decided to use it (I'm guessing by your wording - no offense - you're here)? Are you familiar with the Java Memory Model and are proficient in using `volatile` members and simple locks (and know the reasons to use them)? Have you explored the contents of, and have practical experience with the advanced structures in `java.util.concurrent`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Threads are tricky. The first time people learn threads concept, they think: "Awesome, now I can run everything in parallel! I will use threads as much as possible everywhere!". But there are pitfalls. Let's start from the `CPU`, that has multiple cores. To a first approximation, the number of threads which can be run simultaneously is equal to the number of cores (detailed comments on that, like [hyperthreading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading), are welcome). So, if you created 100 threads, only 4 can be executed simultaneously on a machine with 4 cores. And there is a thread scheduler, which schedules threads for execution.

The process when thread scheduler gives `CPU` time from one thread to another is called [context switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) and it takes some time. Moreover, when you create a new thread you allocate some memory for its stack. Considering that, having many (let's say 50) threads is bad because:

- you are using extra memory. On a `x64` machine default thread stack size is `1MB`. 50 threads = `50 MB`.
- `context switch` happens too frequently, you are loosing time on that.

You'll end up with having many threads, that most of the time do nothing, just wasting resources. So, what's the solution? Instead of creating new threads each time you need to execute some task asynchronously, you can use `ExecutorService`, there is a nice [article](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html) on that. Also, looking at your code, it looks like you are executing recurrent task. If so, you can use [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class, just create [TimerTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) and [schedule it at fixed rate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29).

Answer (score 0):

It is more efficient to have your tutorial as sprites and use the Sprites Update and draw methods. That way you are only using the one thread to update everything. Having more then one thread do the work is a waste.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, the tutorials aren't image-based. They are dynamically rendered using the same code that renders the actual game. Converting the results of a number of OpenGL renderings to a sprite sounds like at least a mild headache, and I imagine it would have to be be more resource intensive than these threads.

Comment: Any waste of system resources is bad in Game programming it is less efficient, plus using a single thread makes sure everything updates in order. Also if you make an empty Sprite class you can have a TutorialSprite that has the above login in its update.  I have no idea how exactly you have gone about it so I am forced to agree it would probably be a headache.